# Strange type mismatch with a macro: found: singleton type with underlying type A, required: A

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect

I have

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B](x: A, y: B) = y
}

class Bar[A] extends Foo[A] {
  override def foo[B](x: A, y: B) = superCall
}
```

where `superCall` whitebox macro should expand to `super.foo[B](x, y)`, and that's what `-Ymacro-debug-lite` shows. The problem is that it fails to compile with following error:

```
[error] /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/scala-dry/src/test/scala/com/github/alexeyr/scaladry/SuperTests.scala:80: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : y.type (with underlying type B)
[error]  required: B
[error]             override def foo[B](x: A, y: B) = superCall
[error]                                               ^
```

Which makes no sense to me: `y.type` is more narrow than `B`, so if it's found when `B` is required it shouldn't be an error. Even stranger, if I replace `superCall` with its expansion `super.foo[B](x, y)`, the error goes away!

`superCall` implementation (slightly simplified by removing irrelevant conditionals, you can see the full version [at Github](https://github.com/alexeyr/scala-dry/blob/8e7ef62d8b1a3e8b6b2a99a895ed3dca4ce08858/src/main/scala/com/github/alexeyr/scaladry/Super.scala)):

```
def superCall: Tree = {
  val method = c.internal.enclosingOwner.asMethod
  val args = method.paramLists.map(_.map(sym => c.Expr(q"$sym")))
  val typeParams = method.typeParams.map(_.asType.name)
  q"super.${method.name.toTermName}[..$typeParams](...$args)"
}
```

EDIT: adding `-uniqid` shows

```
[error]  found   : y#26847.type (with underlying type B#26833)
[error]  required: B#26834
[error]             override def foo[B](x: A, y: B) = superCall
[error]                                               ^
[error] one error found
```

which explains how the error is possible, but doesn't explain *how* 2 `B`'s are different. I tried renaming `B` to `C` in case one of them referred to `Foo.foo`'s `B`, but it still shows `C` with 2 different ids even though there is only one `C` in the program.

EDIT 2: see [Scala typer stage says two uses of type parameter are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598936/scala-typer-stage-says-two-uses-of-type-parameter-are-different). The tree typer produces here (with `super.foo[B](x, y)` instead of `superCall`) is

```
class Foo#26818[A#26819] extends scala#22.AnyRef#2757 {
  def <init>#26822(): Foo#26818[A#26819] = {
    Foo#26818.super.<init>#3104();
    ()
  };
  def foo#26823[B#26824](x#26827: A#26819, y#26828: B#26825): B#26824 = y#26828
};
class Bar#26820[A#26821] extends Foo#26818[A#26821] {
  def <init>#26831(): Bar#26820[A#26821] = {
    Bar#26820.super.<init>#26822();
    ()
  };
  override def foo#26832[B#26833](x#26836: A#26821, y#26837: B#26834): B#26833 = Bar#26820.super.foo#26823[B#26834](x#26836, y#26837)
};
```

so it seems `superCall` expands to `Bar#26820.super.foo#26823[B#26833](x#26836, y#26837)` instead.

Comment: Changing `args` to `method.paramLists.map(_.map(_.asTerm.name))` should work, although I'm not sure I can make a good case about why at the moment.

Comment: @TravisBrown It does work for this case! Unfortunately, it breaks a different test (when parameters are shadowed, I want to use the original parameters). Hm, maybe I should throw an error, or at least a warning, in this case instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your life harder by trying to funnel your type information back through the names of type parameters - simple names are a very lossy medium of exchange - but why are you supplying the type arguments at all? In the absence of evidence to the contrary, you should write `q"super.$methodName(...$args)"` and they will be inferred.

Comment: See http://scastie.org/16282 for an example where not supplying the type parameters fails to compile.

Comment: How can I provide the type parameters other than by name? If I pass `TypeSymbol`s, I get "Can't unquote List[SuperImpl.this.c.universe.TypeSymbol]".

Comment: Re the gist, oh yeah, I forgot for a millisecond there are so many other bugs which underlie any given effort. Type arguments are types, not symbols. Try .asType.toType. The awfulness of that .asType.toType reminds me of what madness it all is. Good luck!

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it brings the type mismatch back (doesn't matter whether I use `asTerm.name` as Travis Brown suggested or `q"$sym"` as I originally had in `args`).