# Scala typer stage says two uses of type parameter are different

Tags: scala

While continuing investigation of [Strange type mismatch with a macro: found: singleton type with underlying type A, required: A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594123/strange-type-mismatch-with-a-macro-found-singleton-type-with-underlying-type-a), I printed the typer phase AST for

```
class Foo[A] {
  def foo[B](x: A, y: B) = y
}
```

with `-uniqid`. The result surprised me, to say the least:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // Test.scala
package <empty>#4 {
  class Foo#7778[A#7779] extends scala#22.AnyRef#2753 {
    def <init>#7868(): Foo#7778[A#7779] = {
      Foo#7778.super.<init>#3100();
      ()
    };
    def foo#7869[B#7870](x#15819: A#7779, y#15820: B#7871): B#7870 = y#15820
  };
}
```

How is the type of `y` not `B#7870`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a scala-internals discussion that sheds some light on this: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-internals/0j8laVNTQsI/discussion.

Comment: Not an existential skolem!